# Data is not displaying properly

Tags: android

I developed an app in android. On first screen, it will ask username and password from the users and then if it is correct it will go to home screen. On Home screen, it will show the details of the events.

The problem is, sometimes on home screen it is displaying the data and sometimes its not even calling the service. I am not getting where i am doing something wrong.

Below is my code for Home:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

int mPosition = -1;
String mTitle = "";
private List<UpcomingJobs> upcomingJobs = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private UpcomingAdapter uAdapter;

// Array of strings storing country names
String[] mMenus ;

// Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable-ldpi/
int[] mOptions = new int[]{
        R.drawable.home,
        R.drawable.internships,
        R.drawable.events,
        R.drawable.logout,

};

// Array of strings to initial counts


private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private LinearLayout mDrawer ;
private List<HashMap<String,String>> mList ;
private SimpleAdapter mAdapter;
final private String MENU = "menu";
final private String OPTION = "option";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    uAdapter = new UpcomingAdapter(upcomingJobs);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new     LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    String url = "url";
    AQuery mAQuery = new AQuery(MainActivity.this);
    mAQuery.ajax(url, String.class, new AjaxCallback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void callback(String url, String data, AjaxStatus status) {
            super.callback(url, data, status);
            if (android.support.v7.appcompat.BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                Log.d("###$Request URL", url + "");
                Log.d("###$Response ", data + "");
                Log.d("###$Status Message : ", status.getMessage() + "");
                Log.d("###$Status Code : ", status.getCode() + "");

            }
            if (null != data && status.getCode() != -101) {

                String StringData = "" + data;
                try {
                    JSONArray rootArray = new JSONArray(StringData);
                    int len = rootArray.length();
                    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                        JSONObject json = rootArray.optJSONObject(i);

                        UpcomingJobs b1 = new UpcomingJobs();
                        b1.Name = json.optString("Name");
                        b1.Position_Name = json.optString("PositionName");
                        b1.EventDate = json.optString("EventDate");
                        b1.EvetnId = json.optInt("EvetnId");

                        upcomingJobs.add(b1);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(uAdapter);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    });



    mMenus = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menus);

    // Title of the activity
    mTitle = (String)getTitle();

    // Getting a reference to the drawer listview
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);

    // Getting a reference to the sidebar drawer ( Title + ListView )
    mDrawer = ( LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);

    // Each row in the list stores country name, count and flag
    mList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("UpComming Events");


    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
        hm.put(MENU, mMenus[i]);

        hm.put(OPTION, Integer.toString(mOptions[i]) );
        mList.add(hm);
    }

    // Keys used in Hashmap
    String[] from = { OPTION,MENU};

    // Ids of views in listview_layout
    int[] to = { R.id.option , R.id.menu};

    // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
    // R.layout.drawer_layout defines the layout of each item
    mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mList, R.layout.drawer_layout, from, to);

    // Getting reference to DrawerLayout
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    // Creating a ToggleButton for NavigationDrawer with drawer event listener
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer , R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close){

        /** Called when drawer is closed */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            highlightSelectedCountry();
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        /** Called when a drawer is opened */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Menu");
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };

    // Setting event listener for the drawer
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    // ItemClick event handler for the drawer items
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                long arg3) {
            if(position==1){
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,About_us.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
            else if(position==3)
            {
                session.logoutUser();
            }

            // Increment hit count of the drawer list item


            if(position < 2) { // Show fragment for countries : 0 to 4
                showFragment(position);
            }else{ // Show message box for countries : 5 to 9
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mMenus[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            // Closing the drawer
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawer);
        }
    });


    // Enabling Up navigation
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    // Setting the adapter to the listView
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}


@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


public void showFragment(int position){

    //Currently selected country
    mTitle = mMenus[position];

    // Creating a fragment object
    CountryFragment cFragment = new CountryFragment();

    // Creating a Bundle object
    Bundle data = new Bundle();

    // Setting the index of the currently selected item of mDrawerList
    data.putInt("position", position);

    // Setting the position to the fragment
    cFragment.setArguments(data);

    // Getting reference to the FragmentManager
    FragmentManager fragmentManager  = getSupportFragmentManager();

    // Creating a fragment transaction
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    // Adding a fragment to the fragment transaction
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, cFragment);

    // Committing the transaction
    ft.commit();
}

// Highlight the selected country : 0 to 4
public void highlightSelectedCountry(){
    int selectedItem = mDrawerList.getCheckedItemPosition();

    if(selectedItem > 3)
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(mPosition, true);
    else
        mPosition = selectedItem;

    if(mPosition!=-1)
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mMenus[mPosition]);
}

  }
```

Comment: Could you add the class `UpcomingAdapter` as well?